# Mongodb c# driver does not return new Id and not set default value

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

In the following code I have two problems.

> 1. The Insert method does not return the Id property.
> 2. The default value that I set to a datetime property was not set.

What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
// I have an Application class:

internal class Applications
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationNameLower { get; set; }
        public DateTime CraetionDate { get; set; }
    }

// I want to keep my class as "clean" as possible so I use a BsonClassMap like this

public void MapStart()
{
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Applications>(c =>
                {
                    c.AutoMap();
                    c.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
                    c.SetIdMember(c.GetMemberMap(a => a.Id));
                    c.GetMemberMap(a => a.Id).SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId).SetIgnoreIfNull(true);
                    c.GetMemberMap(a => a.ApplicationName).SetElementName("ap");
                    c.GetMemberMap(a => a.ApplicationNameLower).SetElementName("apl");
                    c.GetMemberMap(a => a.CraetionDate).SetElementName("cd").SetDefaultValue(new DateTime(2001,2,21));
                });
}

// I have a helper method to return a collection:

private static MongoCollection<Applications> ApplicationsDb
        {
            get
            {
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(_connectionString);
                MongoServer mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
                MongoDatabase db = mongoServer.GetDatabase("mydbname");
                return db.GetCollection<Applications>("apps");
            }
        }


//I have an insert method:

private Applications CreateApplication(string applicationName)
        {
            Applications app = new Applications()
            {
                ApplicationName = applicationName,
                ApplicationNameLower = applicationName.ToLower()
            };

            try
            {
                WriteConcernResult wcResult = ApplicationsDb.Insert(app);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            return app;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The insert method does not return the ID property because it returns a WriteConcernResult, apparently.  (This assumes your sample code compiles.)  Since the Insert method is defined in the driver framework, you can't change this.

2) Where do you call `MapStart()`?

<s>3) Never do this:</s>

```
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

It serves only to erase your stack trace, destroying information that might be useful in diagnosing a problem.

Comment: I call the MapStart() first thing in the program. I know about the exception handling, but for the purpose of the showing the my problem it's OK.

Comment: @user3689486 I have to correct myself -- the thing you shouldn't do is `throw ex;`.  If you just `throw;` as you have here, then the entire try-catch is just a no-op.  I'm still not sure why you expect the insert method to return the ID.  Also, I don't see how the map would know that it should apply the default value to the instance you pass to `Insert`.  Perhaps you should use the `BsonClassMap.CreateInstance` method instead of `new Application`.